How do i query items from mongodb 2 different fields and in inside nested object
I try to query the following:
app.get("/api/leagues/:leagueId/:fixtureDate", async function (req, res) {

  const result = await client.db("db").collection("matches").find({
    $and: [
        { "date": req.params.fixtureDate },
        { "league.id": req.params.leagueId }
    ]
}).toArray();
  res.send(result);
});

League object looks like this:
"league": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "UEFA Champions League",
    "country": "World",
    "logo": "CL.png",
    "flag": null,
    "season": 2024,
    "round": "1st Qualifying Round"
  }

But it returns an empty array [] when it should return fixtures that match the query filter
I experimented around a little bit and found that the problem has something to do with league.id, The server does receive the parameters from the frontend fine so it's not that nor a typo mistake.

This could be an issue:  data types of the fields you are querying on the database and the data received from the web application front end.

league.id is a number while req.params.leagueId is a string, I don't think MongoDB will automatically do type coerce. Use parseInt() or unary plus + to match the datatype:
app.get("/api/leagues/:leagueId/:fixtureDate", async function (req, res) {

  const result = await client.db("db").collection("matches").find({
    $and: [
        { "date": req.params.fixtureDate },
        { "league.id": +req.params.leagueId }
      ]
    }).toArray();
  res.send(result);
});

